# How to type my recursive function for updating nested object properties?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am working on an private pet project on NodeJs. I originally coded in JavaScript and I am now trying to migrate to TypeScript. I am using a couple of utility functions in my project, mostly based on examples I got from the book "Grokking Functional Programming", and I am trying to add types to them.

When trying to write the type signature for a recursive function that can update nested object properties, I got stuck and I would be very grateful if someone here could offer some advice.

I have an "update" function that can transform object properties based on a given object, key and transformation function:

```
type Update = <
  O extends Record<string, unknown>,
  K extends keyof O,
  F extends (val: O[K]) => O[K]
>(
  obj: O,
  key: K,
  modify: F
) => O;

const update: Update = (obj, key, modify) => {
  const copy = { ...obj };
  modify(copy[key]);
  return copy;
};
```

Here is my "nestedUpdate" function that takes a "key" array describing the path to the nested object:

```
const nestedUpdate: NestedUpdate = (obj, keys, modify) => {
  if (keys.length === 0) return modify(obj);
  const [key1, ...restOfKeys] = keys;
  return update(obj, key1, (val1) => nestedUpdate(val1, restOfKeys, modify));
};
```

So far I tried the following type signature:

```
type DeepKeys<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Record<string, unknown>
    ? [P] | [P, ...DeepKeys<T[P]>]
    : [P];
}[keyof T];

type NestedUpdate = <
  O extends Record<string, unknown>,
  K extends DeepKeys<O>,
  F extends (obj: O) => O
>(
  obj: O,
  keys: K,
  modify: F
) => O;
```

For the recursive "nestedUpdate" call on the last line of the function I get the error:

```
Type 'Record<string, unknown>' is not assignable to type 'O[keyof O]'.

  'Record<string, unknown>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'O[keyof O]', but 'O[keyof O]' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'unknown'.ts(2322)

update.ts(6, 13): The expected type comes from the return type of this signature.
```

How could I fix this?

Comment: The TS compiler will never be able to verify that a function implementation respects your generic conditional `DeepKeys` type, so once the typings are correct you'll still need to use a type assertion (people often call this a "cast") to get it to work. But right now your typings seem weird.  Why so many generic type parameters? Why would `modify` in `nestedUpdate` act on `O` and not the property type? Are you asking to fix those typings or the compiler error?

Comment: See prev comment... I would probably give your functions [these typings](https://tsplay.dev/NBB2nN).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That does meet my needs, thank you very much! I am new to TS and self-taught and still a little overwhelmed sometimes. If you could explain your solution that would be really great...

Comment: Note that I assumed `modify` actually does return the new value instead of actually mutating its argument.  Therefore you need `copy[key] = modify(copy[key]);`.  If that's not how it works then presumably it should just return `void` and not `O[K]`.  Hopefully you can tweak that yourself if need be.

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript type checker is essentially unable to perform higher-order reasoning about [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depend on [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters.  The "deep indexing" operations that involve a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of property keys are almost always written as generic conditional types, and therefore the type checker can't really verify that any function that uses them is implemented correctly.  You'll need to come up with the types as best you can, verify their correctness yourself, and then use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or the like to tell the compiler that it shouldn't bother checking it.

---

Anyway, first I'd probably change your `Update` types so that the `modify` function parameter doesn't have its own generic type parameter; there's no need for it since it's expressible purely in terms of `O` and `K`:

```
type Update = <O extends object, K extends keyof O>(
    obj: O,
    key: K,
    modify: (obj: O[K]) => O[K]
) => O;

const update: Update = (obj, key, modify) => {
    const copy = { ...obj };
    copy[key] = modify(copy[key]); // <-- make sure to do the assignment!
    return copy;
};
```

---

Then for `NestedUpdate` we need to be careful.  Conceptually `modify` acts upon the type of the nested property, not on the object type `O`.  My approach here would probably be to define `DeepRecord<K, V>` (the recursive version of [`Record<K, V>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)) and `DeepIdx<T, K>` (the recursive version of the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `T[K]`) and use them to define the types of `obj` and `modify`:

```
type DeepRecord<K extends PropertyKey[], V> =
    K extends [infer K0 extends PropertyKey, ...infer KR extends PropertyKey[]] ?
    { [P in K0]: DeepRecord<KR, V> } : V;

type DeepIdx<T, K extends PropertyKey[]> =
    K extends [infer K0 extends PropertyKey, ...infer KR extends PropertyKey[]] ?
    K0 extends keyof T ? DeepIdx<T[K0], KR> : never :
    T;
```

Both `DeepRecord` and `DeepIdx` use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) with [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to parse the `K` tuple and either build up or drill down into an object type.

Just to test them:

```
type TestDeepRecord = DeepRecord<["x", "y", "z"], number>;
// type TestDeepRecord = { x: { y: { z: number; }; }; }

type TestDeepIdx = DeepIdx<{ x: { y: { z: number } } }, ["x", "y", "z"]>
// type TestDeepIdx = number
```

And now for `NestedUpdate`:

```
type NestedUpdate = <
    O extends DeepRecord<[...K], any>,
    const K extends readonly PropertyKey[],
>(
    obj: O,
    keys: K,
    modify: (obj: DeepIdx<O, [...K]>) => DeepIdx<O, [...K]>
) => O;
```

Here, instead of [constraining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `K` to `DeepKeys<O>`, I've constrained `O` to `DeepRecord<K, any>`.  It's the flip side of the same constraint (instead of "the keys must properly index the object", it's "the object must be properly indexed by the keys") and it's easier to write this way.  `DeepKeys` will tend to make a large [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) and could bog down the compiler (especially if your object is of some tree-like recursive type).  And other techniques to mitigate that don't play nicely with inferring a tuple of [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) for `K`.  And the type `modify` operates on is `DeepIdx<O, K>`.

Well, I'm using `[...K]` instead of `K`.  That's because I've given `K` a [`const` type parameter modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) to signal that we'd like it to be inferred as a tuple of literals and not just `string[]`.  But this tends to infer [`readonly` tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types).  Rather than complicate `DeepRecord` and `DeepIdx` to accept `readonly` tuples, I just wrap `K` in a variadic tuple to convert.

---

As for the implementation `nestedUpdate`, recall that we can't expect the compiler to verify its safety.  I'll just give `obj` and `keys` the intentionally unsafe [`any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) to forestall the warnings:

```
const nestedUpdate: NestedUpdate = (obj: any, keys: any, modify) => {
    if (keys.length === 0) return modify(obj);
    const [key1, ...restOfKeys] = keys;
    return update(obj, key1, (val1) => nestedUpdate(val1, restOfKeys, modify));
};
```

And again, that means we are taking responsibility for making sure it's correct.

---

Let's try it out:

```
const foo = { a: { b: { c: 123, d: "efg" }, h: 456 }, i: 789 };
const bar = nestedUpdate(foo, ["a", "b", "c"], x => x * 2); // okay
console.log(bar); // { a: { b: { c: 246, d: "efg" }, h: 456 }, i: 789 };
nestedUpdate(foo, ["a", "b", "z"], x => x * 2); // error, property z missing in foo subkey
nestedUpdate(foo, ["a", "b", "d"], x => x * 2); // error, string not number
```

Looks good.  The proper call is validated, and note that the `modify` argument's callback parameter is inferred [contextually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing).  The bad calls give errors... if you pass in a bad path, there's an error on the object (saying that it isn't properly indexed by the path).  If your `modify` function doesn't do the right thing with types, you get an error there (since `foo.a.b.d` is a `string` not a `number`, then `x => x * 2` isn't a good `modify`).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAqmAmBDY0C8UA8B5KEAeKAdvAM5QD2ARgFYQDGwANFANK4ETFkDWEI5AMyhYAfAAoAUFGkUaALmGMpM3iAUslMqAFty8AJYC1UMVWoKsAbRYBdAJRRUI4dZsSHT4QG4JEuuUISYCgAVwRkCAU4JBRHEzNmVWZdAyMPZwBvZWl-QOD-MBA4jKgAOnKzKABfHy0CkEtVGziUwxAxesa+e1qZACcIYBC+wih6nxrfUEgoABEICDAAJXpyPvgMNnwiUigABT7ySD7QFj5LG2YANWdUbNZ2HbJLfUIBCD7WAAZHzl2Do4fU58ZjlUqvd6fFhLX5cfaHY7Aho2ZoAfnuJUseygr2+NgU80WK38602S2uziqUAUVx8Emm0EJYAAkvA8BgACrMLYcOEAxEgM7I273HlPKAvN4fb6w-4IoGCkFlcoQ6XQ2VkfkKoUXNGin7bP48PiCKAcqCouYLFlsznWL6XVhLZwKQgQABu0rk9w5dIZZogQSZxLW8DiwdWpMsACI8NHmNGQPGoNGAF7Rx2EELaSgfEQ+AD0Bag-o5geAEZJYfQJTwChKxhKqdd2dzfS81Q7NWqU3A0DLQetrLw4aHttr9agjagzagWZz0qpS+YMbjCaTCfTNhEEiLJb7AcHi2HcXnbd7MwAcuWIPBohE4hh7jhDXDK6GMJYwbZmIhCCARE0GRciCB5X12AZEHgAIABsii1E5FWRJRxHuMwLCA6RVBIdRMJ0PQ2gUUx5CtY9bSwFdv23dJSJtdkKIlKidxorA6RA4I3SCW97xQBRry4u9wlidBiPMKA-xARI+Bw8T-2SAi0kcTJ7kMExsNKGDOAAc2AAALRxUHQL4HAGIYRnw1J2jMOxehyAJQK6EAAEZQXKAYgiwAQhRIZp0Gw2yoFM4ZRjCGIIFEqTnOYMR3UQGCnJoziUEEsKYrilzAvLTzvPkyy7BsiRJj8ezggEchyGKcTJ0oSc6AUJyACYAGZmHgBRowgAQtOjapmF0hQABYAFYADZepxBQAHYAA4AE5O2KvIoEoRBPnQJLuKE8KyvIFdo0QZNo0oQ66AzZgR08EcACooAamyoD3chuEQEBFpIchNI08gtLEFa+nuvcSkQaraoUBqBpG1r2s67rxv6qBhrGqpmH0Ka5oWjaUoiMQdr2g6E2OzczqgC7nGu26AeLD5Dj6ZgwHlRCZx0fQSBIV4tJxUYdqgEgQkoVQJExnjtvKvHDsJlN4GJ0mSagG67o7PdqbWZggj6dm53IDjWw+CQgA)

Comment: Amazing, this is so helpful! This gives me a lot to think on and learn from. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Please consider accepting the answer (if it is acceptable, of course).